# I have a List of inputs which has to be converted into a defined format in Java

Tags: java

Not sure about the best way to get this List in below format. Please suggest better way to get this format in Java. And also below list is dynamic. Sometimes the values can go up to 10 or more

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
```

Now we want the above list to be printed as below -

```
[{"key" : "ABC"}, {"key" : "DEF"}, {"key" : "GHI"}]
```

I tried to use MultiMap like below

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

multimap.put("key", "ABC");
multimap.put("key", "DEF");
multimap.put("key", "GHI");
```

Which prints values like

```
{key=[ABC, DEF, GHI]}
```

Comment: In a map, keys can't be duplicated. Keys should be unique.

Comment: Yes. I used MultiMap not Map. if you have any other sugesstion, you are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Are you willing to convert this list to json?

Comment: @AbdulAlimShakir if that makes job simple, please suggest

Comment: If it's just a question of *printing* the way you showed, then you can try `System.out.println(multimap.entries().stream().map(e -> String.format("{\"%s\": \"%s\"}", e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: @ernest_k This looks great. In this case, Can I also Just format the List instead of going for MultiMap again ? I mean the List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"); as in the same format with 'Key' as same for the values in the list

Comment: Will it always be the same key for each element of the list (such that you can hard-code it there)?

Comment: @ernest_k Yes. the Key value is same. Hardcoding is also fine. But in the above example, you are using map. Can we just use for List and get the same format ?

Comment: Sure, you can `list.stream().map(e -> String.format("{\"key\" : \"%s\"}", e)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @ernest_k I see an error as 'Incompatible types. Required String but, 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variables(s) T exits so that List<T> confirms to String.'

Comment: @hdevi `list.stream().map(e -> String.format("{\"key\" : \"%s\"}", e)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString(); ` You need to convert it to `String` using `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can access underlying entries structure `multimap.entries()` and format the string as per the need.

```
multimap.entries().stream()
      .map(entry -> String.format("{\"%s\": \"%s\"}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**ernest_k** has already provided a couple of nice ways to get the desired string in the comment section. You can extend those solutions by writing a custom class that can take a key.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
MapKeyToValues keyValues = new MapKeyToValues("key", list); // change key as per your need
System.out.println(keyValues);
String formattedString = keyValues.toString();
```

Custom converter class.

```
public class MapKeyToValues {
    private final String key;
    private final List<String> list;

    public MapKeyToValues(String key, List< String > list) {
        this.key = key;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString( ) {
       // need to handle null cases here
       return list.stream()
                .map(value -> String.format("{\"%s\" : \"%s\"}", key, value))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable. So you have to set again in the list the value. Try this one.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){                  
    list.set(i,"{\"key\" : \""+list.get(i)+"\"}");
}
```